# Sometimes Scene Builder in JavaFX doesn't open

Tags: javafx

It's really getting annoying and tiresome when I'm working really hard on something I need to complete and then I need to make a few changes to the GUI so I open Scene Builder and it doesn't open up.

**I've tried** 
- Closing Eclipse and opening it.
- Killing the scene builder process and opening it.

**What works**
- Logging off and logging on and then opening eclipse & the scene builder.

This is starting to make me lose taste in JavaFX. Though I have to use this over Swing.

Also, when I open Scene Builder (from my desktop) it opens up just fine, though when I navigate to my Main.FXML (inside my project). Scene Builder can't be opened. It just does nothing when I open it, and it minimizes.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Even though this question has been asked some time ago, I want to contribute my solution to this problem because it differs from the other solutions and in addition is **very simple**.

This particular problem happened to me just a few mins ago and all I took to solve was maximizing the actual Scenebuilder window!

- Open the *Windows Taskmanager*
- Switch to the applications tab
- Right click the SceneBuilder (named: yourFileName.fxml)
- **Select 'Maximize'**

Description above works for Windows OS, on other OS the corresponding application managing program should do the same.

That worked for me just perfect. No copying and/or overwriting needed.

Comment: unbelievable.  that was the fix for me too.

Comment: yep. It Worked! I couldn't open scenebuilder for a specific fxml neither from eclipse nor from the scenebuilder itself (opening it as an application then trying to open the file), if I copy-pasted it to the desktop, then scenebuilder opened as usual. But this trick worked for me as magic, thanks!

Comment: 2018 and this problem is still a thing... and so is this solution!

Answer (score 9):

Its not the perfect answer but it works well. Try doing the following

> 1.Open scene builder directly from your local drive.
>
> 2.Click on File-> Open Recent -> Clear Menu

Then try to open up your fxml. 
Works fine for me.

Comment: Most people talk about this being an issue for Eclipse, but it's also an issue for Netbeans. Since I had previously opened this from netbeans when I had multiple screens opened, the Scene Builder would be off screen when back on a single screen. Clearing the menu solved the problem for Netbeans as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.  It appears that either SceneBuilder or IntelliJ IDEA put my FXML file in a state that Scenebuilder can't parse.

You may find it helpful to edit the logging.properties file and reopen the bad FXML file.  On windows it's  %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Oracle\JavaFX Scene Builder 2.0\app\logging.properties.  You can set

`.level = ALL`

Then examine the file %TEMP%\scenebuilder-2.0.log for clues.

Valid java.util.Logging levels in descending order are:

```
OFF
SEVERE 
WARNING
INFO
CONFIG
FINE
FINER
FINEST
ALL
```

Also, copy the FXML file to a temp dir.  Try to open it there.  I did that and it appears to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, copying the code from the .fxml file that didnt work with scenebuilder to a new (!) .fxml file on lets just say the desktop and then opening that one worked. After I opened the new file I saved and overwrote it back to where it was in my source folder, and it worked just fine from there on.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Open scene builder directly from your local drive.
> 2. Click on File-> Open Recent -> Clear Menu

this also works for me, try this