# Eclipse - Scenebuilder not starting with right clicking and "Open with scenebuilder"

Tags: java, eclipse, scenebuilder

I have a JavaFX project with several .fxml files. I used to open those files by right-clicking on them and selecting "Open with SceneBuilder". Probably after some operating system maintenance, SceneBuilder does not start anymore. No error message appears, just nothing happens. I' working under XUbuntu 16.04, same behavior on Eclipse Neon and Eclipse Oxygen, the latter with fresh install.
SceneBuilder path is correctly set under Window -> Preferences -> JavaFX -> SceneBuilder executable.
I tried reinstalling e(fx)clipse, nothing.
Tried to reset SceneBuilder by removing ~/.scenebuilder and ~/.java/.userPrefs/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/.
This happens with SceneBuilder 8.4.1 and 8.3.0 . I'm using the executable jar version of SceneBuilder (scenebuilder-8.4.1-all.jar).
Of course, launching SceneBuilder alone and opening fxml files from the filesystem works.
Does anybody have an idea on how to restore the functionality or at least a way to understand whats happening? Many thanks

Comment: Possible related: [Sometimes Scene Builder in JavaFX doesn't open](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24338412/8097737)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the packaged version of SceneBuilder solved the problem.
Downloaded scenebuilder-8.4.1.deb, installed with "sudo apt-get install ./scenebuilder-8.4.1.deb". Then configured Eclipse pointing "Window->Preferences->JavaFX->SceneBuilder executable" to "/opt/SceneBuilder/SceneBuilder".
This also solves the problems related to window maximization/minimization not working properly with SceneBuilder executable jar file.