# SceneBuilder won't open in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, scenebuilder

When I try to open an FXML file on SceneBuilder **through Eclipse**, it will not open. However,

1. When I open SceneBuilder on its own and then try to open an FXML file on SceneBuilder through Eclipse, it works as expected. But if I try to open it through Eclipse first then try to launch SceneBuilder on its own, it doesn't work.
2. When I try to open the FXML file and check Task Manager afterwards, SceneBuilder is not on there.
3. If I close Eclipse, then SceneBuilder launches with the requested FXML file.

I've tried the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338412/sometimes-scene-builder-in-javafx-doesnt-open) but to no avail. I'm on Eclipse 2020-12 and SceneBuilder 15.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have used certain libraries like JFoenix,which you havent imported in Scenebuilder. That creates problems sometimes.
HAve you linked your scenebuilder with Eclipse ??

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32483890)